# ICINGA2 - wrong host status (DOWN/UP) for a while

Tags: windows, hosts, icinga2

I have setup and configured ICINGA2 server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I added majority of my hosts (mainly Windows hosts) and I noticed that sometimes ICINGA2 shows wrong hosts status for a while (1 minute or so). For example plenty of my hosts are **DOWN** status but I know that all hosts works properly all the time, and after next check interval hosts change their status to **UP** in ICINGA2.

Does anyone know why ICINGA2 monitoring system shows wrong host status?

Comment: I suspect IDO. Icinga need to refresh status in it sdatabase.

When you use icinga-classic CGI, it update like a charm - it reads Icinga status from files. However using Icingaweb2 needs IDO and the database looks stale for a while (even minute in some large deployments).

Comment: See mailing list issue: https://lists.icinga.org/pipermail/icinga-users/2016-January/010657.html